# Create soulbound NFT using solana token extension

Tags: spl-token, nft, token-extensions

I want to create soulbound NFT (aka nontransferrable NFT) using Solana token extension specifically with the [nontransferable token extension](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/non-transferable). How do I achieve this and how do I specify the metadata?

Comment: Here's my own post engaging with the similiar topic [https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/creating-spl-token-non-transferable-extension-with-metadata-on-react](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/creating-spl-token-non-transferable-extension-with-metadata-on-react)

Answer (score 2):

The best place to find out how to do this are the official docs.

The [Immutable Owner](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/immutable-owner) and [Metadata](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer) guides describe the steps in detail.