# Creating SPL token Non-Transferable Extension with metadata on React

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, spl-token-program, token-2022, mpl-token-metadata, umi

I'm trying to create SPL token with Non-Transferable Extension with metadata.
Right now I can create token with each features only follow [these](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions) guides, and fails to combine them.
below is how I tried to create Non-transferable token with metadata.

```
const { connection } = useConnection();
const { publicKey : walletPublicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

  const deployTokenSolana = useCallback(async () => {
    // Generate new keypair for Mint Account
    const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    // Address for Mint Account
    const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
    // Authority that can mint new tokens
    const mintAuthority = walletPublicKey;

    const tokenATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mintKeypair.publicKey, walletPublicKey, false, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);

    // Metadata to store in Mint Account
    const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
      updateAuthority: walletPublicKey,
      mint: mint,
      name: "OPOS",
      symbol: "OPOS",
      uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/opos-asset/main/assets/DeveloperPortal/metadata.json",
      additionalMetadata: [
        ["description", "Only Possible On Solana"]
      ],
    };

    // Size of MetadataExtension 2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length
    const metadataExtension = TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE;
    // Size of metadata
    const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;

    // Size of Mint Account with extension
    const mintLenNT = getMintLen([ExtensionType.NonTransferable]);
    const mintLenMP = getMintLen([ExtensionType.MetadataPointer]);
    const mintLen = mintLenNT + mintLenMP

    // Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
      mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
    );

    // Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
    const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: walletPublicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
      newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
      space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
      lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
    });

    // Instruction to initialize the MetadataPointer Extension
    const initializeMetadataPointerInstruction =
      createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
        mint, // Mint Account address
        walletPublicKey, // Authority that can set the metadata address
        mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );

    // Instruction to initialize the NonTransferable Extension
    const initializeNonTransferableMintInstruction =
      createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(
        mint, // Mint Account address
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
      );

    // Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
    const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
      mint, // Mint Account Address
      tokenDecimals, // Decimals of Mint
      mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
      walletPublicKey, // Optional Freeze Authority
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
    );

    // Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
    const initializeMetadataInstruction = createInitializeInstruction({
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
      metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
      updateAuthority: walletPublicKey, // Authority that can update the metadata
      mint: mint, // Mint Account address
      mintAuthority: mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
      name: metaData.name,
      symbol: metaData.symbol,
      uri: metaData.uri,
    });

    // Instruction to update metadata, adding custom field
    const updateFieldInstruction = createUpdateFieldInstruction({
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
      metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
      updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
      field: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // key
      value: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][1], // value
    });

    const associatedTokenAccountInstruction = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      walletPublicKey,
      tokenATA,
      walletPublicKey,
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    const mintToInstruction = createMintToInstruction(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      tokenATA,
      walletPublicKey,
      tokenTotalSupply * Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals),
      undefined,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Add instructions to new transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAccountInstruction,
      initializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
      initializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
      initializeMintInstruction,
      initializeMetadataInstruction,
      associatedTokenAccountInstruction,
      mintToInstruction
    );

    const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { signers: [mintKeypair] });

    console.log(
      "\nCreate Mint Account:",
      `https://solana.fm/tx/${signature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
    );
  }, [walletPublicKey, connection, sendTransaction]);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?, or if there's any other approaches to implement this.
Thanks

Comment: edited my post with my recent updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I could solve the issue with this.

```
    // Size of MetadataExtension 2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length
    const metadataExtension = TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE;
    // Size of metadata
    const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;
    
    // Size of Mint Account with extension
    const mintLen = getMintLen([
      ExtensionType.MetadataPointer,
      // ExtensionType.TokenMetadata,
      ExtensionType.NonTransferable,
    ]);
    
    // Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
      mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
    );
    
    // Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
    const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: walletPublicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
      newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
      lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
      space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
    });
    
    // Instruction to initialize the MetadataPointer Extension
    const initializeMetadataPointerInstruction =
      createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
        mint, // Mint Account address
        updateAuthority, // Authority that can set the metadata address
        mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );
    
    // Instruction to initialize the NonTransferable Extension
    const initializeNonTransferableMintInstruction =
      createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(
        mint, // Mint Account address
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
      );
    
    // Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
    const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMint2Instruction(
      mint, // Mint Account Address
      tokenDecimals, // Decimals of Mint
      mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
      freezeAuthority, // Optional Freeze Authority (default: null)
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
    );
    
    // Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
    const initializeMetadataInstruction = createInitializeInstruction({
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
      metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
      updateAuthority: walletPublicKey, // Authority that can update the metadata
      mint: mint, // Mint Account address
      mintAuthority: mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
      name: metaData.name,
      symbol: metaData.symbol,
      uri: metaData.uri,
    });
    
    const tokenATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mintKeypair.publicKey, walletPublicKey, false, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);     

        const associatedTokenAccountInstruction = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
            walletPublicKey,
            tokenATA,
            walletPublicKey,
            mint,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        );

        const mintToInstruction = createMintToInstruction(
            mint,
            tokenATA,
            walletPublicKey,
            tokenTotalSupply * Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals),
            undefined,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        );

    // Add instructions to new transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAccountInstruction,
      initializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
      initializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
      // note: the above instructions are required before initializing the mint
      initializeMintInstruction,
      initializeMetadataInstruction,
      associatedTokenAccountInstruction,
      mintToInstruction,
    );
```

the problem might be calculating the mintLen and lamports for the extensions, and the order of instructions in transaction.

Comment: No probs, glad you posted your own answer to help others!

Comment: Hi @cablespecific, I'm stuck in minting the SPL token SPL2022 with metadata on frontend. Could you please share how I can do this?

Comment: I edited the example above for minting additionally

Comment: Thanks for reply - I already do this, whenever I start the frontend server I get an error: Buffer is not defined

Comment: Whenever I install the latest version of Spltoken @0.3.11 got an error 
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/state.js

Comment: Hi @cablespecific - could you please varify those version, as I got error from spl-token-metadata....   
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.11",
    "@solana/spl-token-metadata": "^0.1.2",

Comment: "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.0",
    "@solana/spl-token-metadata": "^0.1.2",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.90.0",